# How to Configure EF Core to Serialize Enum as String in Cosmos DB for complex Properties

Tags: json, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am working with EF Core and Azure Cosmos DB in a .NET project. I have a User entity which contains a collection of AuditStandardUserInfo entities. Both the User entity and the AuditStandardUserInfo entity have a Competence property of type AuditCompetence (an enum). I want to configure EF Core to serialize the Competence property as a string in Cosmos DB, but I am encountering issues with the proposed solutions I've tried so far.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
public enum AuditCompetence
{
    None,
    Low,
    Medium,
    High
}

public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    // ... other properties ...
    public ICollection<AuditStandardUserInfo> UserAuditStandards { get; set; } = new List<AuditStandardUserInfo>();
    public AuditCompetence? Competence { get; set; }
}

public class AuditStandardUserInfo
{
    public string AuditStandardId { get; set; }
    // ... other properties ...
    public AuditCompetence Competence { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ... configuration code ...
    }
}
```

I have tried using the HasConversion() method in the OnModelCreating method, as well as applying the [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] attribute from the Newtonsoft.Json library to the AuditCompetence enum, but none of these solutions have worked for me. Only the enum directly under User was converted correctly with HasConversation(), not the one in UserAuditStandards

Could someone please guide me on how to correctly configure EF Core to serialize the Competence property as a string in Cosmos DB, both for the User entity and the AuditStandardUserInfo entity?

Answer (score 0):

> How to Configure EF Core to Serialize Enum as String in Cosmos DB for complex Properties

**Below are the steps I followed:**

- The entity classes **User** and **AuditStandardUserInfo** are defined.
- **User** class has a property named `Competence` of type `AuditCompetence` that you want to serialize as a string in Cosmos DB.
- The subclass of **DbContext** called **MyDbContext** is used to control database interactions.
- It has two `DbSet` attributes called **Users** and **AuditStandardUserInfos** that represent the database tables for the appropriate entity types.
- The `UseCosmos` method made available by the EF Core Cosmos DB provider is used to configure the Cosmos DB connection in the `OnConfiguring` method.
- In the `OnModelCreating` method, configure the model for the database.
- The `Competence` field of the `User` entity is set to be converted to a string when stored in the database using the `.HasConversion<string>()` method. This is how to make sure the enum is serialized as a string in Cosmos DB.

**Below Is the code I tried with:**

```cs
public enum AuditCompetence
{
    None,
    Low,
    Medium,
    High
}

public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    
    public AuditCompetence? Competence { get; set; }
}

public class AuditStandardUserInfo
{
    public string AuditStandardId { get; set; }
    public AuditCompetence Competence { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AuditStandardUserInfo> AuditStandardUserInfos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string endpoint = "*****";
        string key = "*****";
        string databaseName = "Database";
        string containerName = "Container";

        optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(
            endpoint,
            key,
            databaseName,
            options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionMode(Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ConnectionMode.Gateway);
            });
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(u => u.Competence)
            .HasConversion<string>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<AuditStandardUserInfo>().HasNoKey();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```js
{
    "UserId": "e21ceaa4-f54c-46f0-8d12-05fe47745c12",
    "Competence": "High",
    "Discriminator": "User",
    "id": "User|e21ceaa4-f54c-46f0-8d12-05fe47745c12",
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly like the output ChatGPT would generate.